# How to Use Vertical/Horizontal Multiples in PowerBI

Tags: excel, data-visualization, powerbi, powerview

I am aware that MS Excel 2016 Power View has handy feature of Vertical Multiples and Horizontal Multiples.

Here is sample output. How to implement this in PowerBI. Cannot find this feature anywhere.

Plz don't tell me we have to manually create pie chart for each month and then pin to dashboard ....

[image]

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer but to be honest...  that's a terrible representation of data. Is purple increasing or decreasing over time? Is teal generally larger or smaller than dark blue? You can't tell that from a bunch of pie charts like that.

Comment: You could do this with the R studio in Power Bi using GGplot, which is already supported by PowerBi

Comment: You can vote for this to implemented [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9750957-vertical-and-horizontal-multiples-small-multiples)